# Parent category and subcategory of active parent category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, blocks, navigation, phtml

Can someone help to understand how to achieve **Magento Category Navigation** in header section.
**Parent Category** like men, women, children
and when I go with any parent category like **MEN**, I want to show subcategories of **MEN** and make it fixed for rest of its sub-subcategory child i.e. when i go with any subcategory i want to show that subcategory-set of active parent category.
like in this website top category navigation : http://www.zalora.sg/

Answer (score 1):

If you know menu file path generally it's be in header.phtml after this code 
 `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>` then you can code something like :

```
    <?php
     // code goes here to get current url
    $currentUrl1 = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(); 
    If($currentUrl1 == 'men'){
        echo 'My men menu html goes here ';
    }
    else If($currentUrl1 == 'women'){

    echo 'My women menu html goes here ';
    }
    else {
    echo 'My default menu html goes here ';
    }
?>
```

Hope this will help you.